# Extent problem with MapServer

Tags: mapserver

I'm new with MapServer and I followed various tutorials to display a shapefile in MapServer. Now I want to use my shapefile but I have this error:

> loadMapInternal(): General error message. Given map extent is invalid.
>   Check that it is in the form: minx, miny, maxx, maxy

my extent[image] field is:

```
EXTENT 4567164.94 4570286.94 614923.216 618804.216
```

These information come from ArcGIS (my colleague opened the shapefile in ArcGIS).

Can someone help me to understand what is wrong?

Comment: You want the order left, bottom, right, top. This equates to minx, miny, maxx, maxy.

Comment: The layer you have highlighted is not a shapefile, it's an ECW.  You say you followed tutorial to display a shapefile in MapServer, but you can't do this...  MapServer is software for providing data not viewing data. So you could use shapefile as an input (for a WMS) of have zipped shapefile as output (for a WFS)

Answer (score 2):

As documented in http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/map.html the numbers must be in order  [minx] [miny] [maxx] [maxy]
Here x means easting or longitude and y northing or latitude. It seems that you should give the extent as

```
EXTENT 614923.216 4567164.94 618804.216 4570286.94
```